# Is there any other reason to Historical Lock buildings?

Tags: bit-city

when you click on a build there is a checkbox near to the bottom saying "Historical" which appears to prevent the building from changing when it upgrades.

so far the only time i needed this is when there was a Bux reward for having 2 Water Towers in a city which came from Service Zones and to stop the first one changing when upgrading i needed to use that Historical Lock.

But is there any other beneficial purpose for this Historical lock?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, doesn't seem to be. The only real use I ever found was to lock them to collect certain numbers of buildings for whatever quest.

I suppose you could also argue that the historical lock allows you to keep buildings so you can effectively "design" your city the way you like.